# Looking for an online sql injection tool checker

Tags: php, web-services, sql-injection

I recover an old website which is full of sql injection, I would need a tool if it exists, that crawl the whole site just by followings existing links on it, then try to put some sql injection contents into weak inputs.

I can check by myself but the site is rather big so I would prefer a crawler, to be sure i do not forget an entry...

thx

Ok after typing this post, I realize that I'm asking for an hacking tool, which is not the case of course :p, so any white hat techno available ?

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=sql+injection+tool

Comment: You can try SqlInjectMe addon for firefox.https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sql-inject-me/
But i don't think it follows the existing links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should fix your known problems before you look for automated tools.

You need to take the following steps:

1. If the site uses a framework, is the framework up to date and patched? The framework is primarily what automated tools will attack, so rather than test it, just get it up to date.
2. Where the site does its own SQL, you need to check every single SQL statement, by hand, to ensure none of them are vulnerable. That means, in every case, either converting to parameterised statements (best) or using `mysql_real_escape_string()` or similar if that is not practical.

You should treat the above as a much higher priority than testing tools. Don't even spend time looking for automated scanning tools until those are complete.

An automated SQL Injection tool is just not going to find all your problems, even those which are obvious to a competent attacker.

**Until you have done both of the above, you will be wasting your time on automated tools.**

Comment: Actually, this is what I already done, but I'm afraid I forgot a file or two, and the major problem is that I do not know which file is in used, coz the webdirectory is full of duplicate, backup file or unused script...This is a homemade framework but old, and maintain by several developers since I just recover it...I'm agree with your answer so I will change my request, perhaps I only need a crawler, to check all the useless files on the server, or something server side, like xdebug or another tool ?